# What is hungup cause hangup.job.timed.out in asterisk or gateaway?

Tags: asterisk, gateway

The calls got disconnected due to hungup cause hangup.job.timed.out. Unable to find route cause. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, this is predominantly a site for programmers and software designers.  It is not a support site for issues related to software, but instead about how to write software and solve problems with written code.  While people do discuss Asterisk when dealing with writing extensions for the platform, discussions of how to troubleshoot Asterisk aren't a good fit here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not problem of asterisk, but problem of library or SDK you are using